# What's a good place to share panoramas online?

Tags: web, panorama, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online viewer for panorama photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/online-viewer-for-panorama-photos)

I've got some Photomerged panoramas, about 5-12MB each. Where's a good place to put them online?

Preferably I'd like a place where they can be uploaded at full quality, with a handy pan/zoom google-maps-like interface, and shared.