# What software do I need to create a panorama inside a cylinder to publish on the web?

Tags: web, panorama

Googling I found on the net reference to sphere panoramas, but I'm not interested in looking up or down, just to the front. My image is a just rectangular, a very wide panorama and I wanted to create a view of it, as if one is inside a cylinder and the inside walls have the texture applied to it. If possible I wanted to publish it to the web.

Comment: Hi Nuno. I don't think this is the right place for this question: as it sounds like you're approaching it from a JavaScript developer's perspective, have you tried Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Well, I just referred to webgl as one of the approaches I've considered, I really wanted some insight by someone that has worked in this kind of situation (if there is anyone), to know how they got to it. I know how to do a panorama using WebGL three.js, the thing is that the image that I'm using does not suit, it requires a different type of panorama. But if here I won't find my answer I might turn to stackoverflow yes.

Comment: The point is, this is a forum for photographers. Most photographers will get as far as "Looking into WebGL three.js..." and give up. If you want to ask "What software can I *use* to do this?", I suggest you rephrase the question to get helpful answers. If you're asking "How can I *write* software to do this?" (which currently you are), Stack Overflow is the right place.

Comment: Really they will quit like that? That misses out the point of this site if the users behave like that, still I want an answer so I'll rephrase this. I'm asking how to create the panorama view not how to write software õ_Ó

Comment: Some possible similar info: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/online-viewer-for-panorama-photos

Comment: This question may also be of some use: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/230/which-tools-are-good-for-creating-panoramas-stitching-multiple-photos

Comment: Photoshop (Extended) has some 3D tools that will create a spherical panorama. As for taking that and putting it to the web I do not know...yet =>

Comment: If you found an answer to your own question, please post the answer as an answer (not as an edit to your question), so that you can accept it and others can vote on it.

Comment: I had a time span due to my low reputation, it's done. Now more 24 hours before I can check it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to it with [WebGL library threejs](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), demo here: http://nunocruz.me/panorama/
Feel free to view the source code of the page and use it if you want to do the same and if you have any questions about it just ask!

Answer (score 2):

Stitch you panorama together using your favorite program then you can try [this program (called Pano2VR)](http://gardengnomesoftware.com/pano2vr.php) which is free to try (will watermark your image) and you can purchase it to remove the watermark.

The hardest part about this all might ensuring you take a seamless 360 panorama.

Update: If you have Photoshop after you stick together the image you can use Zoomify to export the file.   File > Export > Zoomify. Does a great job.

Update 2: I happen to come across creating a Virtual Tour using jQuery. So [here is the link for "jQuery Virtual Tour."](http://www.openstudio.fr/jQuery-virtual-tour.html?lang=en)

Comment: cool feature, didn't know about it, it's a shame that it does adapt to the browser screen size. Thanks for it though!

Comment: @nuno_cruz - From what I read about it you can edit it fully as they give you the source code though I have not tried it. =>