# How to publish super-mega/gigapixel panoramas?

Tags: software, panorama, publishing

Flickr, Picasa Web, SmugMug, Zenfolio are all the wrong places to publish massive things like this. They have awful limits. I haven't been able to find a gigapixel host that is like Flickr/Picasa Web/SmugMug/Zenfolio but dedicated to massive panoramas.

This brings me to my question and purpose of thread: how can I publish my gigantic panorama? I know there are viewers out there, surely they aren't custom designed for every particular website by the webmasters of that site. Could you recommend me to software and tools for publishing massive panoramas on my own web resources? Advices, tips, and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: We've had this question before, try searching with different terms. Gigapixel does not give anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Online viewer for panorama photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/online-viewer-for-panorama-photos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion @ 90€ is have your own web host and run a copy of http://krpano.com/

Samples:

Multi-Res: http://krpano.com/examples/multires/

Normal: http://krpano.com/examples/normal/#top

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox or some other file-sharing oriented service which happens to make it easy to view pictures?

Answer (score 1):

I do not use this service so I can't give you a lot of details, but I know Microsoft's [Photosynth](http://photosynth.net/default.aspx) web site hosts large (several gigapixels) panoramas and has a decent web based viewer for them.

What I'm not sure is if you can upload panoramas that you built with your own tools as opposite to using their [ICE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/ice/) stitching software. Hopefully someone who has used the service can comment on that.

Comment: Photosynth has been shut down.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to host them on SmugMug, if you're willing to do a little bit of work to put the pieces together. A user on dgrin has written pretty thorough directions on how to do it: http://www.dgrin.com/showthread.php?t=208690

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest you a software or tool. Publishing pictures on the Internet is usually very simple but you have to keep in mind that very heavy pictures are difficult to display on the Internet because of the bandwidth of visitor's connection.

The best advice that I can give you is to compress your panorama (<5MB) and, if you want, propose to download the high quality version. Regarding the storage of high quality pictures, I suggest you to have a look to web hosting providers. I think that for $10/month you can enjoy 100GB a storage and unlimited traffic. An example: http://www.ovh.co.uk/web-hosting/, ...

Answer (score -1):

you can also upload, host and annotate your images at gigapan.com